# Solving $f''(y) - (n \pi / \alpha) f(y)= \frac{B}{n^3}\left [1 - \frac{\cosh(n\pi y)}{\cosh (n \pi \alpha)}\right]$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How to solve the following PDE

$$f''(y) - (n \pi / \alpha) f(y)= \frac{B}{n^3} \left[1 - \frac{\cosh(n\pi y)}{\cosh (n \pi \alpha)}\right],$$

where $\alpha, B, n$ are constants.

I have solved the homogeneous equation but have trouble finding a particular solution.

Comment: Try something $C+D\cosh(n\pi y)+E\sinh(n\pi y)$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ L(D)f=\bigg(D^2-\frac{n\pi}{\alpha}\bigg)f $$
and the equation becomes
$$ L(D)f=\frac{B}{n^3} \left[1 - \frac{\cosh(n\pi y)}{\cosh (n \pi \alpha)}\right]=\frac{B}{n^3}-\frac{B}{2n^3\cosh(n\pi\alpha)}e^{n\pi y}-\frac{B}{2n^3\cosh(n\pi\alpha)}e^{-n\pi y}. $$
Thus a particular solution is
\begin{eqnarray}
f_p&=&L(D)^{-1}\bigg(\frac{B}{n^3}-\frac{B}{2n^3\cosh(n\pi\alpha)}e^{n\pi y}-\frac{B}{2n^3\cosh(n\pi\alpha)}e^{-n\pi y}\bigg)\\
&=&\frac{B}{n^3}\frac{1}{L(0)}-\frac{B}{2n^3\cosh(n\pi\alpha)}\frac{e^{n\pi y}}{L(n\pi)}-\frac{B}{2n^3\cosh(n\pi\alpha)}\frac{e^{-n\pi y}}{L(-n\pi)}\\
&=&\cdots.
\end{eqnarray}